# class `Csv` in RailsCst #396

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine, railscasts

Here is a link to the [repo on github](https://github.com/railscasts/396-importing-csv-and-excel)

So in this RailsCast, Ryan uses a class named `Csv` (line 28 in store-after/app/models/product.rb). He is also using the `roo` gem. However, `Csv` is not a class in the API nor is it found anywhere in the rdoc for the `roo` gem.

So where did it come from? I'm trying to re-create his code in Ruby 4.1 with no luck, because I don't understand where this class came from.

I have looked through his previous railscast, #362, and the github repo for that episode [can be found here](https://github.com/railscasts/362-exporting-csv-and-excel/tree/master/store-after). However he doesn't use any class other than the `CSV` class of the language proper.

Where does this clas come from? Is it some sort of typo that was auto corrected by Rubymine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in [the ChangeLog](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1120---2013-08-18) that `Roo::Csv` was renamed to `Roo::CSV` in 1.12.0.